# How to make KineticJs custom shape

Tags: html, kineticjs, shapes

I am trying to make  KineticJs html 5 custom shape.

But it is not working in Google chrome. Not draggable in Firefox and also shape are not same in size.

Can anybody tell why?

live code http://jsfiddle.net/prantor19/wGE2a/8/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'canvas-container',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

drawWindow = function(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.attrs.x,this.attrs.y);
    context.lineTo(this.attrs.width,this.attrs.y);
    context.lineTo(this.attrs.width,this.attrs.height);
    context.lineTo(this.attrs.x,this.attrs.height);
    context.closePath();
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(img,this.attrs.img_x,this.attrs.img_y);
}

img = document.createElement('img');
img.src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Nature_reserve_Kladrubska_hora_in_summer_2011_(17).JPG/1024px-Nature_reserve_Kladrubska_hora_in_summer_2011_(17).JPG";

var window1 = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: drawWindow,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    img:img,
    img_x:0,
    img_y:0,
    draggable: true
});

var window2 = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: drawWindow,
    x: 10,
    y: 60,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    img:img,
    img_x:-250,
    img_y:0,
    draggable: true
});

pointercursor = function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}
defaultCursor = function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}

window1.on('mouseover',pointercursor );
window1.on('mouseout', defaultCursor);
window2.on('mouseover',pointercursor );
window2.on('mouseout', defaultCursor);

layer.add(window1);
layer.add(window2);

stage.add(layer);
```

Comment: in terms of dragging, you need a drawHitFunc as well, not just a drawFunc. I think. But consult the custom shape tutorial on html5canvastutorials.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has errors in it

> Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. kinetic-v4.3.2-beta.js:4365
>   Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Chrome refuse to work with cross domain images on cavas.

For dragging, you need to add this set stroke for the shape

```
stroke: 'black',
```

and at the end of drawFunc

```
canvas.fillStroke(this);
```

Here is the my working version from yours

http://jsfiddle.net/W7SGT/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the canvas renderer when drawing a custom shape in KienticJS, or else it has no way to handle the events on the shape.  Here's a tutorial on custom shapes:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/

you might also take a look at the Kinetic.Image shape to see how it handles images specifically:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/shapes/Image.js

Comment: Also, if you're creating the custom shape so that you can use clipping, you may want to try out v4.3.4 which will be released later this month.  It includes clipping functionality at the container level.